# How to run stored procedure in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I added this code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TestAdonetEntity2Entities entityContext;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        entityContext = new TestAdonetEntity2Entities();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dataGridView1.DataSource =  entityContext.SelectMyCustomer();
    }
}
```

But this code will cause an error:

```
public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<MyCustomer> SelectMyCustomer()
{
     return base.ExecuteFunction<MyCustomer>("SelectMyCustomer");
}
```

The error is:

> An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.

My stored procedure...:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_MyCustomer]
as
begin
  select * from  dbo.MyStuffs
end
```

My Columns:

CustomerID PK ink 
Name nvarchar(50)  
SurName nvarchar(50)

Comment: what is in your InnerException ??

Comment: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.MyStuffs'."}

Comment: i refreshed my Question.

Comment: The error message says: that table you're trying to select from does not exist - in this case, your sproc will never work.

Comment: Have you tried running the stored procedure from SSMS or something alike? Tell us the results!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx) about using sprocs in Entity Framework.

And [another one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx)